# Optimization of virtual function call

Tags: c++, optimization, virtual-functions, vtable

I have a question regarding optimization of virtual function calls. I have read somewhere (and the problem is I can't find the article now) that it might be possible to optimize away the v-table look-up by using a construct similar to this:

```
// Base.h
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

// Concrete.h
class Concrete : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        // do something;
    }
};

//Some.h
extern Base* const g_object;

// Some.cpp
Concrete on_stack_concrete;

Base* const g_object = &on_stack_concrete;
```

The trick is supposed to be using a const pointer to a variable that is allocted on the stack (not dynamicaly) and that a compiler most certainly will optimize that away. So whenever a user calls g_object->Foo() the //do something part will be executed without need for v-table look-up.

Is that true or not?

Thanks in advance for any replay.

EDIT:

The possible usage of such construct is to limit the interface of concrete implementations. Of course one can argue that "restricted" methods should be private, but sometimes other modules of the library need access those public additional methods of the object without allowing user to manipulate those. So for example using #defines, one can create code similar to:

```
// Some.cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
Win32Concrete concrete;
#elif defined _UNIX
UnixConcrete concrete;
#endif

Base* const g_global = &concrete;
```

In fact the declaration of these classes can be defined only in CPP file therefore, the user is unaware of their existance.

The question is not *why* to use such constant pointer in the first place, but if it is possible to optimize away the v-table lookup in such scenario.

Comment: Thats probably compiler dependent, you should be able to verify this looking at assembly generated by your compiler

Comment: Why use a pointer if it always points to the same object?

Comment: @BoPersson, I can think of one good application right now, for example cross platform library that exposes only abstract interfaces to the users and the back-end uses multiple implementations for various platforms depending on some #defines. This would of course need multiple compilation for each platform with different set of defines, but still for the end user it makes no difference.

Comment: If the Win32Concrete class is not visible to clients of Some.h, then they are unlikely to be able to optimize out the vtable since they can't see what it "really is", since you don't decide that until link time. At any rate vtable optimization is not guaranteed, so there is no way to force it except by not having a vtable in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misusing `virtual`.

`virtual` implements run-time polymorphism.  And the scenario you describe doesn't use or need that.  It's unlikely that both `Win32Concrete` and `UnixConcrete` exist in any compilation environment.

Instead of:

```
// Some.cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
Win32Concrete concrete;
#elif defined _UNIX
UnixConcrete concrete;
#endif

Base* const g_global = &concrete;
```

use:

```
// CommonHeader.h
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef Win32Concrete Concrete;
#elif defined _UNIX
typedef UnixConcrete Concrete;
#endif
```

Now your functions don't need to be virtual.

Comment: The point of global variable initialized this way is to avoid passing it to the functions as parameters wherever it is needed, so such scenario just won't happen. It is global, thus it is accessible everywhere so the "contex" as You mentioned, does not change in my understanding.

Comment: @AdrianLis if you are accessing the global variable directly, then why create `Base* const g_object` at all?.  You could use `on_stack_concrete.foo()` instead.  And in that case, you can avoid the lookup.

Comment: Because concrete class can expose different (additional) interface to the user which he should not be able to use directly. That is why the pointer to base class is in place that limits the inteface only to vital stuff. I will edit the question to show the possible usage.

Comment: I am aware of such solution, but again You sir, have missed one important point of the external exposure. Base is public interface for the users of a library. The concrete implementations are meant to be details for the internal implementation of the library and each can differ quite extensively. Internally of course I do use the concrete variable where "richer" interface is needed, but the user should get unified interface no matter what the internal implementation uses, and since this does not change at runtime and it is compiled this way, the question is if the v-table lookup is inevedible.

Comment: Of course I could use adapter or wrapper for the concrete implementations that would limit the interface but this would require to do a lot of preprocessor macros and additional coding for every new implementation. Using run-time polymorphism is easier in this context but somehow unnecessary cost of virtual functions arises. That is why I asked is the solution I read about viable option

Comment: @AdrianLis I would consider reexamining why you want to use virtual functions.  Or ask a new question on how to implement a compile-time interface without them.

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach used in the Doom 3 source code (https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG/), for example neo/framework/FileSystem.h defines this:

```
extern idFileSystem *       fileSystem;
```

And neo/framework/FileSystem.cpp defines this:

```
idFileSystemLocal   fileSystemLocal;
idFileSystem *      fileSystem = &fileSystemLocal;
```

The only discussion I could find about it is this: http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/

> idTech4 high level objects are all abstract classes with virtual methods. This would normally involves a performance hit since each virtual method address would have to be looked up in a vtable before calling it at runtime. But there is a "trick" to avoid that.
>
> Since an object allocated statically in the data segment has a known type the compiler can optimize away the vtable lookup when commonLocal methods are called.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to make the classes which need access to the restricted method friends of the Concrete class. Then they get full access to the class, and everybody else gets only public access.

If that is not practical, you can put the implementation in the base class with all the restricted methods protected, then derive a special class that exposes the protected methods.

```
class Concrete
{
public:
    void foo() { ... }
protected:
    void bar() { ... }
};

class ConcretePrivate : public Concrete
{
public:
    void bar() { Concrete:: bar(); }
};

ConcretePrivate g_globalPrivate;
Concrete& g_global = g_globalPrivate;
```

Code which uses `g_global` can access only Concrete methods. Code which uses `g_globalPrivate` can access ConcretePrivate methods.